# How to restart the Java Process with -Djava.library.path?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java-web-start

I have an application that is started with JWS. The first time user launches this application he has to choose a path where Berkeley DB XML is installed. I do need this to set the native library path and restart the application with -Djava.library.path parameter. Berkeley DB XML java bindings uses JNI to make calls to the database. Since our users may have different OS I cannot rely on a default location.

So, I have a problem with getting current classpath. When I print out "java.class.path" it only gives me "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Resources/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar". I have three jars that I cannot find in my sys props.
on my Mac.

I hope this was understandable and thanks for any tips beforehand.

Comment: That's really weird, to my mind, to use a DB engine hosted on user machine when you could use a remote DB, or even a pure Java DB, downloded with your web startable application).

Comment: Well, its not my decision to make on how the DB is used. The organisation where I work is using Berkeley DB XML in an embedded mode  to store and query the XML using XQuery. That is the reason for that.

Comment: Did you try `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "path_to_libs");` instead of restarting?

Comment: Yes, and that did not help, I guess due to security you are not allowed to set this property at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to repaire permissions with DiskUtil.

Avoid using this pattern. What you could do is to store the command and execute that simulating that you are starting a new process.